# Cant Latex parse "_" an underline sign?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, latex

I try to plot some data with matplotlib and will render the text wit Latex (Mitex).
But it seems, that Latex can not render an String with an "_" like "Value_One"
Is there a way so solve this?
Becaus nearly all my data has an underline sign in their names.

```
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'Value_'

Here is the full report generated by latex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/Kolja/.matplotlib/tex.cache/e48a8cb85f6079b1df37bc64344a9a7f.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))

("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/type1cm\type1cm.st
y")
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty"
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1enc.def"
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1enc.dfu"))
) ("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.st
y")
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.
sty"
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.st
y")
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.s
ty")
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifvtex.
sty")
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ifxetex\ifxetex.
sty")
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.
cfg")

Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (5058.9pt) is ignored.


Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    `height' (5058.9pt) is ignored.

) (e48a8cb85f6079b1df37bc64344a9a7f.aux)
("C:\Users\Kolja\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd")
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.14 ...e{10.000000}{12.500000}{\rmfamily Value_
                                                  }
No pages of output.
Transcript written on e48a8cb85f6079b1df37bc64344a9a7f.log.
```

This is my Code for the Graph:

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8})
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = "Linux Libertine"
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text/48633

Comment: If you have thing like `Value_One` you should not set them as normal text, but as verbatim

Comment: i tried to do it this way:`plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{underscore}') ` , after installing the packege in MiKTex, but its jut generates a timeouterror in jupyter.

Comment: after deleteing the cache from MiKTex it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install the underscore package in your Tex interpreter and run this:

```
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{underscore}')
```

(maybe you have to delete the cache from Tex)